# MySQL doesn't recognize time of day in a date column

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

So, I want to insert in my table a date variable that contains the date AND the time (minute, hour, second) of a message that gets posted.
My problem is that no matter what type of data my `DATE_POSTED` is (`DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`), it still saves my information at the time `00:00:00`.

Here is my Java code that gets the current time and then posts the message.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = calendar.getTime();

    Message msg = new Message(user, message, date);
    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(msg);
```

This is the result (for some reason I can't upload my image):

```
_____________________________________
|ID|USER|MESSAGE|DATE_POSTED        |
| 1|asd |qwery  |2013-03-15 00:00:00|
| 2|asd |321tgg |2013-03-15 00:00:00|
-------------------------------------
```

I want to mention that my Java code is fine, because at breakpoint, it has the time values.

Comment: What does your Hibernate configuration look like?

Comment: show us your Meesage mapping resource.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using DATE as the type for that field.  Try using DATETIME instead, if you care about timezones, or just TIMESTAMP if you don't.